# presentModalViewController not displaying toolbar?

Tags: ios, view, uitoolbar

I have a viewcontroller I am trying to display as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet, however it does not show its UIToolbar. How can I make a toolbar show up on it?

```
ConnectionEditViewController * connectionEditViewController = [[ConnectionEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConnectionEditViewController" bundle: nil];
connectionEditViewController.modalInPopover = YES;
connectionEditViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
connectionEditViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController: connectionEditViewController animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a UINavigationController instance, set the rootViewController to be your connectionEditViewController, then configure the modal properties for the UINavigationController and present that.

If this is on iPad, it should pop up the view with the Navigation Bar as a grey toolbar at the top.
Configure the navigationItem of the connectionEditViewController to configure the nav bar.